# Why is GNU Indent doing what it seems to be a self rule violation?

Tags: formatting, indentation

I'm using **GNU Indent** to format some code. I have some lines like this one:

```
port->N[0].BTR.U = (DIV8(0U)    |
                    TSEG2(0x3U) |
                    TSEG1(0xEU) |
                    SJW(0x3U)   |
                    BRP(0x9U));
```

That are being formatted to code like this:

```
port->N[0].BTR.U = (DIV8(0U) | TSEG2(0x3U) | TSEG1(0xEU) | SJW(0x3U) | BRP(0x9U));
```

I am using the **-l80** command that, according to the documentation, should break the line at 80 characters. Here the code was originally shorter than that but after the formatting, the resulting line is beyond the 80 characters! So how is indent violating it's own rule? Also as far as I understand I didn't specify any command for doing this, I mean, taking code from several lines and place it in one single line.

And this is really annoying because I don't want this to be modified. So, does anybody know what command or combination of commands can I use to avoid this?

These are the commands I'm already using:

> -ndj -nbad -bap -nbc -nbbo -hnl -bl -bli0 -bls -blf -ncdb -nce -cp1 -ncs -di2 -nfc1 -nfca -hnl -i4 -ip0 -lp -npcs -nprs -psl -saf -sai -saw -nsc -nsob -cli4 -cbi0 -nut -nbs -npsl -l80 -c90 -cd90

Regards!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Freiheit why are there other questions regarding GNU indent here on stackoverflow not being voted as off-topic?

Comment: In voting to close I made a call on this question not all the questions remotely related to the topic across all of SO. A question about a GNU tool over at Unix.SE might get an answer since thats definitely on topic for Unix.SE. Wether this is on or off topic for SO will come down to what other users and the review process thinks. Wether or not my close vote is right or wrong, you might try asking at Unix.SE and see if you get an answer. Your question is well written, you just gotta get it in front of the right expert for a solution!

Comment: @Freiheit: I think I'll do that because I'm not getting any answers. Thanks.